# decoding blob into original file

Tags: decryption

I have a program which converts file to blob in sqlite database. It uses QT framework. I can normally save the file from the database but only through its GUI (which is really painful).
I want to be able to decode the blob in sqlite to the original file.
I have attached the original and encoded file here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2BLH3kVAYbgQVVzTTFRRzNHMlk/view?usp=sharing)
(click download button)
It is likely using qtarray and qstring but I am not sure. It seems also that the header is removed while encoding.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blob file is compressed with zlib, so you have to decompress it first. The first 4 bytes of the blob is the decompressed size and the compressed content start at 6th byte.

After the decompression you got binary file starting with `0xDEADBEAF` (in big-endian, marked as yellow in the figure). After it you can find some header parameters, one of the `0x22` (marked as green) is the number of rows.

After the header you can find the row data as 32-bit float ([see float conversion here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=BFBF589F)):

```
6 = 06
0.756431 = 0x3f41a578
-1.494892 = 0xbfbf589f
```

[image: Decompressed blob]

Comment: I am really so much thankful for this....
I got everything except the part you said (one of the 0x22 (marked as green) is the number of rows.).....what do you mean by number of rows=22

Comment: 0x22 = 34, and you had 34 rows in your xed file (see the first line of it)